# Factory calling alternate constructor (classmethod)

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, class-method, factory-boy

I am struggling finding a way to have a class Factory (I use `factory_boy` version 2.11.1 with Python 3) using an alternate constructor defined as a `@classmethod`.

So let's say we have a class for building a 2D-point object with a default constructor and 2 additional ones:

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @classmethod
    def fromlist(cls, coords):  # alternate constructor from list
        return cls(coords[0], coords[1])

    @classmethod
    def duplicate(cls, obj):  # alternate constructor from another Point
        return cls(obj.x, obj.y)
```

I create a basic Point factory:

```
import factory

class PointFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Point
        inline_args = ('x', 'y')

    x = 1.
    y = 2.
```

By default, it seems to call the constructor `__init__` of the class which seems very logical. I could not find a way to pass `inline_args` as being `coords` for using the alternate constructor `fromlist`. Is there a way to do so?

This is my first experience working and building factories in general so I may also be looking up at the wrong keywords on the web...

Comment: Not having used factory boy, what happens if you make `model = Point.fromlist`?  Semantically, they're both callables accepting arguments and return `Point` instances -- I feel like this might be one approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of `factory_boy` is to make it easy to produce test instances. You'd just call `PointFactory()` *and you are done*, you have test instances for the rest of your code. *This usecase doesn't need to use any of the alternative constructors, ever*. The factory would just use the main constructor.

If you are thinking that factory_boy factories must be defined to test your extra constructors, then you have misunderstood their use. Use factory_boy factories to create test data for *other code to be tested*. You'd not use them to test the `Point` class (other than to generate test data to pass *to* one of your constructors).

Note that `inline_args` is only needed if your constructor doesn't accept keyword arguments at all. Your `Point()` class has no such restriction; `x` and `y` can be used both as positional and as keyword arguments. You can safely drop `inline_args` from your definition, the factory will work regardless.

If you must use one of the other constructors (because you can't create test data with the main constructor), just pass the specific constructor method in as the model:

```
class PointListFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Point.fromlist

    coords = (1., 2.)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, which triggers 2 extra questions:

- I added `inline_args` because I want to create 2 points that are different from each other for some tests so I can pass values into the factory. Is it bad practice?

- Also, can we think of using factories for avoiding the creation of objects within other functions that are not for tests? It seems to me that functions creating new objects instances cannot be independently unit-tested otherwise.

Comment: @Eskapp: you don't need to set `inline_args` to be able to pass different values into the factory. You can just call `PointFactory(x=42.)` and it'll use the default `y` value and your specific `x` value to create a new `Point()` object, either way. `inline_args` doesn't govern that functionality.

Comment: @Eskapp: factory_boy is *purely there for tests*. Classes are themselves factories already; you call a class to produce an instance. What factory_boy does is give you more options to generate test instances, in bulk, for specific predefined scenarios, etc, with random generated data that looks realistic, and with support for complex hierarchies of objects all produced by further factory_boy factories.